# How to show a multivariable limit at a point $\textbf{x}$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$ doesn't exist by the path method?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am studying multivariable limits (ML's) in vectorial calculus. My question is at the point 2.

*''does not exist" : DNE

I know when solving a ML whether

1. The limit will yield a real value when it is continuous at $\textbf{x}$
   ,whether
2. The limit does not exist at $\textbf{x}$; and hence you should show there are at least two different values the limit takes when it approaches to $\textbf{x}$ from different paths **A, B, C,  ...** etc.:

So, from a path **A** the non-existing limit may be a real value *p*,and from other path **B** it may produce $\infty$, and from a path  **C** a *s* $\in\mathbb{R}$  ; my question is:

In order to show the ML DNE, Is it enough to show that the ML is $\infty$ from the path **A**, and is *p*$\in\mathbb{R}$ from a path **B**, and hence we've got two different results? or should the two results given by the differents paths **A** and **B**  be real numbers, different from $\infty$ ?

In the same way, may I just prove the limit DNE by showing from a path **A** it produces $\infty$ and from a path **B** it is $-\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that you get different limits from two different paths, even if those limits are $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

The reason is, if $\lim_{\textbf{x}\to\textbf{a}} f(\textbf{x})$ exists and equals $L$ (where $L$ is a real number or $+\infty$ or $-\infty$), then the limit of $f(\textbf{x})$ along *any* path to $\textbf{a}$ will be $L$. So if two paths give two different values to $L$, then in fact $L$ cannot exist.

Comment: First of all, I thank you. Your answer fulfilled my expectation.